# CSpice in Visual C++ 2015: Link errors

Tags: c++, c, linker-errors

I'm trying to use Nasa's CSpice toolkit, but when I try to build my code I receive errors like

`LNK2028    unresolved token (0A0004E6) "extern "C" void __cdecl spkpos_c(char const *,double,char const *,char const *,char const *,double * const,double *)"`

I have already placed the library (cspice.lib) into the linker
[Project Property page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJmsG.png) and imported the headers.
Any ideas on what the issue might be?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Calculation.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

SpiceDouble* Calculation::sunPosition()
{   
//--Kernels--
//Load Earth data
furnsh_c("..\data\earth_pck\earth_latest_high_precision.bpc");
//Load LeapSeconds tabulation for time convertion
furnsh_c("..\data\all_spk\naif0011.tls.pc");
//Framework used is J2000, so it does not need to be loaded


//--Variables--
SpiceDouble epochTime;
SpiceDouble sunPosition[3];
SpiceDouble lightYears;

//--Calculation--
//Seconds past J2000 TDB
time_t t = time(0);
struct tm* utcNow = gmtime(&t);
std::string month;
switch (utcNow->tm_mon)
{
case 0:
    month = "JAN";
    break;
case 1:
    month = "FEB";
    break;
case 2:
    month = "MAR";
    break;
case 3:
    month = "APR";
    break;
case 4:
    month = "MAY";
    break;
case 5:
    month = "JUN";
    break;
case 6:
    month = "JUL";
    break;
case 7:
    month = "AUG";
    break;
case 8:
    month = "SEP";
    break;
case 9:
    month = "OCT";
    break;
case 10:
    month = "NOV";
    break;
case 11:
    month = "DEC";
    break;
}

std::stringstream format;
format << (utcNow->tm_year + 1900) << " ";
format << month << " " << utcNow->tm_mday << " ";
format << utcNow->tm_hour << ":";
format << utcNow->tm_min << ":";
format << utcNow->tm_sec;

ConstSpiceChar* et = format.str().c_str();
str2et_c(et, &epochTime);

//Get current sun position relative to earth, using earth as the inertia center
spkpos_c("sun", epochTime, "iau_earth", "none", "earth", sunPosition, &lightYears);
printf("%f", sunPosition);

return sunPosition;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Solution: library was x64, Visual C++ was configured for x86.
 -> Ran "vcvarsall.bat amd64" in cmd and changed the project to build x64